# Writing a HTML string content with array values in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

What I'm trying to accomplish is to write a html string in a controller with array values being looped in it. So for example;

```
$content = "Your store, at location A, has these items added to them". add array loop here. "Do take note!";
```

My array would be as such

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbdf',
    'name' => 'Diamond bracelet (sample)',
    'tags' => 
    array (
      0 => 'female',
      1 => 'jewelry',
    ),
    'category' => 'Accessories',
    'sku' => '1029EHW',
    'priceType' => 'Fixed',
    'unitPrice' => 190,
    'cost' => 90,
    'trackStockLevel' => true,
    'isParentProduct' => false,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbdb',
    'name' => 'Long-sleeved shirt(sample)(M)',
    'tags' => 
    array (
      0 => 'tops',
      1 => 'cotton',
    ),
    'category' => 'Women\'s Apparel',
    'sku' => 'ABC1234-M',
    'priceType' => 'Fixed',
    'unitPrice' => 47.170000000000002,
    'cost' => 20,
    'trackStockLevel' => true,
    'isParentProduct' => false,
    'parentProductId' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbd4',
    'variationValues' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'variantGroupId' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbd5',
        'value' => 'M',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

note that the array can have many instances of product_name and sku, or can have none.

How do i populate this in my string to be like;

```
$content = "Your store, at location A, has these items added to them, 1) asd, 2)def, 3)asf . Do take note!
```

Comment: You can use foreach loop in your controller

Comment: yeah i can loop it with a foreach, but how do i populate the $content area with all the values from the foreach?

Comment: like what i want is, in $content, i want my array values in that string. so if i do a foreach, it would not show all values in that one string, just 1 per instance?

Comment: "note that the array can have many instances of product_name and sku, or can have none." Can you explain more about your array?

Comment: @AliKhalili do check my latest edit

Comment: Do you get this array as a collection?

Comment: yes @IGP it's from a collection and i pushed it into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be

```
$content = "Your store, at location A, has these items added to them";
$array = array(0=>["product_name" => "abc", "product_sku" => "def"], 1=>['product_name' => 'kdkf', 'product_sku'=> 'ljbkj']);

for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++){
  $content .= ($i+1).") ".$array[$i]['product_name].' '.$array[$i]['product_sku'].', ';
}

$content .= "Do take note.";
```

This way you're just constantly concatonating the string value in separate parts instead of trying to inject it in the middle of the parent string.

not tested, may be syntax errors

Comment: Sure thing. without testing it in my editor, i'm sure i missed something syntax-wise...but the concept is there. just continually add a new string on to the end of the last one, then add the final "do take note" to the very end of it when the loop is done

Comment: I just edited my answer after testing in my editor. Should be good to go now

Comment: ok so, after checking it out, it returns the products properly, however the numbers in front of the products are not there. so it shows something like "product a, sku 1245" instead of "1) product a, sku 1234"

Comment: check my update. you just add $i+1 with a contcatonated parenthesis in front of the loop string

Comment: glad i could help!!

Comment: ', ' will be printed for all products. According to his description, Last product doesn't have ','

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I've used \sprintf for ease, check if the output serves your purpose.

```
<?php

function stringMethod(): string
    {
        $count = 0;
        $arrayString = [];
        $array = [['product_name' => 'abc', 'product_sku' => 'def'],['product_name' => 'abc', 'product_sku' => 'asd']];

        foreach ($array as $value){
            $count++;
            $arrayString[] = sprintf('%s)%s', $count, $value['product_sku']);
        }

        $string = \implode(',', $arrayString);

        return \sprintf("Your store, at location A, has these items added to them %s Do take note!", $string);
    }

    echo stringMethod();
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer suggestion! will try it out as well!

Comment: Sure let me know how it goes, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. try to do it in less number of lines

$content = "Your store, at location A, has these items added to them, ";

```
    $productArray = array (0 => array ('id' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbdf','name' => 'Diamond bracelet (sample)','tags' => array (0 => 'female',1 => 'jewelry',),'category' => 'Accessories','sku' => '1029EHW','priceType' => 'Fixed','unitPrice' => 190,'cost' => 90,'trackStockLevel' => true,'isParentProduct' => false,),1 => array ('id' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbdb','name' => 'Long-sleeved shirt(sample)(M)','tags' => array (0 => 'tops',1 => 'cotton',),'category' => 'Women\'s Apparel','sku' => 'ABC1234-M','priceType' => 'Fixed','unitPrice' => 47.170000000000002,'cost' => 20,'trackStockLevel' => true,'isParentProduct' => false,'parentProductId' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbd4','variationValues' => array (0 => array ('variantGroupId' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbd5','value' => 'M'))));  

    foreach ($productArray as $key => $product) {
        $content .= ($key+1).') '.$product['name'];
        if (count($productArray)-1!=$key) {
            $content .= ', ';
        }
    }
    $content .= ". Do take note!";
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer suggestion! will try it out as well!

Answer (score 1):

```php
$content = "Your store, at location A, has these items added to them,". $this->getItemList($collection) .". Do take note!"
```

```php
# Somewhere else in the controller
protected function getItemList(Collection $collection): string
{
    return $collection->pluck('name')
                      ->merge($collection->pluck('sku'))
                      ->map(function($item, $key) { 
                          return ($key + 1) . ') ' . $item; 
                      })
                      ->implode(', ');
}
```